# How to Internally redirect from home page to Catalogue page in Django-oscar?

Tags: django, django-oscar

I'm using Django-oscar for my project. After Django-oscar config, I can see localhost:8000 empty,  Instead, I want to redirect to localhost:8000/Catalogue Page

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', application.urls),
]
```

I expected output is. when i run `localhost:8000` it should take to `localhost:8000/catalogue`

Comment: Simply add `url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/catalogue/'))` in your `urlpatterns` before the `application.urls` line. See docs - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview